# python3 how to make a cookie string to cookiejar

Tags: python, python-3.x

python3.4

```
import http.cookiejar

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

str_cookie = 'sg=89f;tb_token_=b711be336563;tt=login.gwcool.com'
```

now, how can i translate str_cookie to cj?

Comment: what do you want to do with the cookie in the cookiejar ?

Comment: thanks verymuch, the reason i need this is : i need to login on chrome and get the cookie string, then use the cookie string relogin with python

Comment: feel free to accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I came up with, let me know if it worked for you, I just added the cookies to `cj` but I dont know if that brings you any further :

See documentation of `Cookie` if you want to set the fields otherwise.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookie-objects

```
cookies = str_cookie.split(";")
for c in cookies:
     k,v = a.split("=")
     cookie = http.cookiejar.Cookie(None, k, v, None, False, "", 
                                    False, "", "",
                                    False,False, False,False,
                                    False,
                                    "",
                                    "",None)

     cj.set_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: From the docs:
class http.cookiejar.Cookie

    This class represents Netscape, RFC 2109 and RFC 2965 cookies. It is not expected that users of http.cookiejar construct their own Cookie instances. Instead, if necessary, call make_cookies() on a CookieJar instance.

Comment: youre right, when I tried it on my machine it worked but i think i need more context to answer the question then

Comment: thanks verymuch, the reason i need this is :  i need to login  on chrome and get the cookie string, then use the cookie string relogin with python